# Maven profile activation using a list of mutually exclusive values

Tags: maven, dependencies, platform-specific

I'm working on a project that depends on SWT. It uses Maven as build tool and dependency management system. Because SWT is platform-dependent, I need to tell Maven which dependency on which platform should be used.

Maven profiles are usually utilized to conditionally include dependencies according to the **os.family** and **os.arch** properties like that:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>Linux-x86</id>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <family>linux</family>
        <arch>i386</arch>
      </os>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <!-- some platform-specific dependency goes here -->
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

The problem is that **os.arch** could have several different values - "i386", "i486", "i586" etc. but, in the SWT world, they all map to "x86".

Is there any possibility to specify a mutually exclusive list of values (os.arch in my precise case) as condition in Maven without the need to create a separate profile for each value?

Comment: As far as I know you can build a product which contains different platforms/architectures etc. and starting that product on an appropriate platform will automatically select the correct artifacts.. ? OSGi ?

Comment: Do you have any further details on how it works in practice? Any examples maybe? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

haven´t tested it but there is an arch `x86`

see the maven doc ....

[Maven Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

[maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireOS.html)

[os arch variables](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/os.html)

Comment: My test machine (Ubuntu 16.04) returns Arch: "i386" in Maven 3.3.9. The project doesn't compile with <arch>x86</arch> but it works with <arch>i386</arch>.

Comment: hm ok another approach... what about defining an required system property, which may be an disjunction  ...http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html

Comment: Yes, setting a system property would be indeed a solution I want investigate further. I've seen somewhere that os.arch will be conditionally redefined to "x86" which is ugly IMHO. In my Gradle scripts, I usually use a simple array remapping which requires only two lines of Groovy code. For the moment being, I don't see how it can be done in a short and elegant way in Maven...